# Suppress android test based on device type?

Tags: android, junit-runner, junit-rule

I run an Instrumentation test suite using Gradle 'connectedCheck' which executes tests on all connected devices. Some tests fail only on certain devices and I want a mechanism to suppress/ignore those tests only for that device.

Can anyone tell me a best way to do it? I am looking into JUnit test rules but wondering if Android provides any API to achieve in a simpler fashion.

Comment: with devices do you mean tabs ?

Comment: No android devices. The instrumentation tests run on android devices.